# How to render results either as JSON or with gsp view depending on the content-type request header?

Tags: grails

I want to reuse the same logic in controllers for both html-view and RESTful API.
What is the best way to do this in Grails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [the `withFormat` method](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html):

(code here taken from that link with JSON added)

```
import grails.converters.XML
import grails.converters.JSON

class BookController {

    def list() {
        def books = Book.list()

        withFormat {
            html bookList:books
            js { render books as JSON }
            xml { render books as XML }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Is it possible to move js/xml part to some common place, like after interceptor? (as it will always be the same)

Comment: @tim_yates, the code you posted won't handle the request content type.  Only deals with the response.  You would need request.withFormat { } as of Grails 2.0.

Comment: @Gregg - The question asks how to return a different response based on "the content-type _request header_", which is what the HTTP request uses to indicate what sort of content types it can accept for a response. Your info about how to handle the format of the request, while useful, does not pertain to the question.

Comment: @Roman what do you mean? You will always be rendering the same response? Perhaps consider asking another SO question regarding what you are after.

Comment: @cdeszaq - right, but how do you suppose you base it on the request header?  The only way to do that in Grails 2.0 is to use request.withFormat, so it does apply here.  withFormat by itself won't look at the request header.  It will only look at the URL; /controller/action.json|xml.

Comment: @Gregg Please take a look at the [Content Negotiation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation) section of the user guide. There are actually 3 different ways to do content negotiation, and the request header is only one of them. The uri extension, as well as a request parameter are also valid ways, and all will use the `withFormat` block to do the rendering. (and yes, there is a precedence ordering among the three ways, but I don't remember it off the top of my head) Note: You may need to set the `grails.mime.use.accept.header` config param to `True`.

Comment: @cdeszaq I don't know why we are arguing about this.  From the docs: "Another important factor to note is that the withFormat method deals with the response format and not the request format. As of Grails 2.0, there is a separate withFormat method made available on the request that you can use to handle the request format which is dictated by the CONTENT_TYPE header of the request:" which is what I am saying.